# Advanced filter excluding three criteria from Excel table

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I'm trying to filter a table with an advanced filter, in which all items can appear EXCEPT for items with an Article Number that contains (or starts with, it doesn't matter) "PDE", "Q", or "M". The regular Excel filter only allows for two filtering criteria, which is why I need an advanced filter. (To clarify, there are many columns in the table, and Article Number is one of those columns.)

However, I have so far been unable to find a way to filter for items that do NOT contain something, although I've done a fair amount of researching, including the Microsoft tutorial [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/filter-by-using-advanced-criteria-HP010073942.aspx). Any ideas? Please let me know if you need more information.

Answer (score 0):

My first intuition is that it is not directly possible. I would write a formula like `=if(<complex condition>,"Y","N")` in an auxiliary column and then filter on that column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with *AutoFilter* You must build an **Array** of all the elements in the column excluding duplicates and excluding *PDE* *Q* and *M*

Here is an example for column **D** in which the header row is row **#2**

```
Sub FilterExcludeThree()
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, c As Collection
    Set c = New Collection
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
    On Error Resume Next
    For i = 3 To N
        v = Cells(i, "D").Value
        If v = "PDE" Or v = "M" Or v = "Q" Or v = "" Then
        Else
            c.Add v, CStr(v)
        End If
    Next
    On Error GoTo 0

    ReDim ary(0 To c.Count - 1)

    For i = 1 To c.Count
        ary(i - 1) = c.Item(i)
    Next i

    ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D" & N).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=ary, _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue might be with having only a single column (though I see no reference to that in the documentation you quote). If your list is in ColumnA, say A7:A17, please try inserting a new ColumnA with say in A2 (A1 blank):

```
=AND(ISERROR(SEARCH("M",B7)),ISERROR(SEARCH("Q",B7)),ISERROR(SEARCH("PDE",B7)))
```

then Advanced Filter, List range: `$A$6:$B$17`, Criteria range: `$A$1:$A$2`.